# Is this Bug? When calculating regression metrics sklearn cross_validate score results not euqal to estimator score resultes

Tags: scikit-learn

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocD4K.png)
svr[0].score(X,y) is not equal to scores['test_score'][0]

I have read the source code. But cant see the detial in _passthrough_scorer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBGdv.png)

I know the meaning of two scores. And I manually use KFold and get each fold test score, the results are like this, they are so different with
scores['test_score']. My results are [0.1900817162767654, 0.9454646872235107, 0.5383648752174341, 0.7844985877839026, 0.9717599124665652]. But scores['test_score'] are [-0.17922386, -0.25855697,  0.14471102,  0.28956888, -0.20603142]. Why this occur?

And when I use classification estimator, cross_validate get similar result with model score.

Code:

```
X = np.sort(5 * np.random.rand(40, 1), axis=0)
y = np.sin(X).ravel()
y[::5] += 3 * (0.5 - np.random.rand(8))

svr_rbf = svm.SVR(kernel="rbf", C=100, gamma=0.1, epsilon=0.1)
scores = cross_validate(svr_rbf, X, y, cv=5,return_estimator=True)
svr=scores["estimator"]
svr[0].score(X,y)
```

Use KFold code:

```
kf=KFold(n_splits=5,random_state=40,shuffle=True)
s=[]
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train=X[train_index]
    y_train=y[train_index]
    X_test=X[test_index]
    y_test=y[test_index]
    s.append(svr[0].score(X_test,y_test))
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

`scores['test_score'][0]` is the (R2) score of a model fitted on the first four folds of your CV split on the fifth fold.

`svr[0].score(X,y)` is the score of that same model on the entire dataset; since that includes the training folds, it is optimistically biased.

---

Regarding your update, where you use loop over a `KFold` split: if it were *the same* `KFold` object, then the first score should come out as the same as the first entry from `scores`.  But the rest won't, because you're explicitly using `svr[0]`, the model trained on the first four folds, to test on every fold.  Instead, you should be looping through `svr` as well.

However, the `KFold` object *is not* the same one as in `cross_validate`.  You can fix that though: just instantiate `kf` first, and pass *that* as the `cv` parameter of `cross_validate`.

Comment: I know that, and I manually use KFold and get test score of each fold. The results are not like scores['test_score']. Just see the  supplementary image.

Comment: just see the supplementary text

Answer (score 0):

Your question is why the `cross_validate()` results (`scores['test_score']`) are different to your manual approach using `KFold()`. The reason is that the way you have used `KFold()` differs from `cross_validate()` in two ways.

The key difference is that `cross_validate()` uses a different estimator for each fold. In your implementation, you keep using the same estimator from fold 0 for each score. Fix it as follows:

```
estimators = scores['estimator'] #List of estimators
...
for fold, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(kf.split(X)):
    X_test=X[test_index]
    y_test=y[test_index]
    #Each fold has its own estimator
    s.append(estimators[fold].score(X_test, y_test))
print('Test score per fold using KFold:\n\t', s)
```

The second difference is that `cross_validate(cv=5,...)` means that it will behave like `KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=False)`. To match this behaviour, change your manual implementation as follows: `kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=False)`.

Here's the complete code:
[image]

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

#Synthetic data
np.random.seed(0)
X = np.sort(5 * np.random.rand(40, 1), axis=0)
y = np.sin(X).ravel()
y[::5] += 3 * (0.5 - np.random.rand(8))

#Using cross_validate
svr_rbf = svm.SVR(kernel="rbf", C=100, gamma=0.1, epsilon=0.1)
scores = cross_validate(svr_rbf, X, y, cv=5, return_estimator=True)
estimators = scores["estimator"]
print(
    'Test score per fold [using cross_validate] :\n\t',
    scores['test_score']
)

#Using KFold() to get the same results as cross_validate()
kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=False) #This matches cross_validate() defaults

s=[]
for fold, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(kf.split(X)):
    X_test=X[test_index]
    y_test=y[test_index]
    s.append(estimators[fold].score(X_test, y_test))
print('Test score per fold [using KFold] :\n\t', s)

#Other information
print()
print(
    'Estimator0 score on the entire dataset:\n\t',
    estimators[0].score(X, y)
)
```